# Add a global pre-build target in Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

We are migrating from Clearmake to Cmake. One project in our codebase uses only one location for all headers (which everybody then includes). With previous Clearmake, we had a target `export_include` that run before the compilation. This target would take all headers specified in a variable and copy them over to the global location. It was even clever enough to copy only missing or changed ones.

Is there a way to replicate this behaviour in Cmake? I had a look at `add_custom_command` and `add_custom_target`. `add_custom_command` can only be used as a part of a build target (not globally) and `add_custom_target` is always considered outdated, so it would always copy all of the headers over and over. Ideally I would run `make export_headers` and it would copy new and changed headers to the shared location. And if I would run `make` (without parameters), it would execute first `export_headers` and only after it would start rebuilding.

In the plain Make terms, normally the installation is done by running

```
make
make install
```

I need something like

```
make export
make
make install
```

And ideally, one `make` target to run all the three above.

P.S. there are more than 1300 headers in dozens of directories and about 150 targets (libraries and binaries), so going back and specify the dependencies per-target is not really an option.

Comment: CMake figures out which headers it needs to include. You just have to tell it which include directories it should use, everything else is done for you, isn't it?

Comment: @usr1234567 Yes, I know which include directory to use and I can easily specify that via include_directories. The problem is to move all the headers there.

Comment: My point is, you should not move the headers, but tell CMake where it can look for them. Copying headers within your source directories is asking for trouble.